# Finding the complex roots of $t^3+2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Finding the complex roots of an equation: $t^3+2$.

Well typically you would set $t^3+2$ to zero and solve for $t$. Where in this case you would get $t=\sqrt[3]{2}$. However I want to find solutions that are in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. What is the trick to get those solutions?

Comment: An equation usually has an equal sign somewhere.

Comment: Rational roots are in particular also real, so in this case there can't be any.

Comment: The trick lies in DeMoivre's theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you would get $t=\sqrt[3]{-2}$, not $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

However, in general, you can always find $n$ solutions to the equation $z^n = w$. if you are given $w$.

In particular, the solutions are found by first writing $w$ in a polar format, i.e.
$$w=r\cdot (\cos \phi + i\sin\phi)$$
where $r$ is a positive real number and $\phi$ is a real number between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Then, the solutions of $z^n = w$ are:

$$z = \sqrt[n]{r}\left(\cos \left(\frac{\phi}{n} + \frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{n} + \frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\right)$$
where $k=0,1,2,3,\dots, n-1$

Comment: So would I let $t=z, n=3$, and $w=-2$?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Yes. And then $r=2$ and $\phi = -\pi$

Comment: Ok. I see why $r=2$ and $\phi=-\pi$. Is there a rigorous procedure to get these results of $r$ and $\phi$?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown There is, yes. You should cover it in class when you will be covering complex numbers. If you want to learn about it yourself, then any textbook on the basics of complex analysis should also cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1)factorize
$$
t^3+2=(t+\sqrt[3]{2})[t^2-\sqrt[3]{2}t+(\sqrt[3]{2})^2]
$$

2) solve  $$(t+\sqrt[3]{2})=0 \qquad \lor \qquad t^2-\sqrt[3]{2}t+(\sqrt[3]{2})^2=0$$

obviously you have not solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$ but you can find solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This is a strange answer to put a downvote on. I wonder if the downvoter would care to explain why he thinks this answer is bad (deserving a downvote)?

Comment: @5xum: Simply I had want to show that , in this case, we can find all solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ without ''advanced'' knowledges about complex numbers.

Comment: O know, that's why I gave you the upvote. I am asking the person who gave the down vote to explain his reasons

Answer (score 0):

Nth Roots lie evenly on a circle in the complex plane.

So the solutions are the negative third root of 2, and the two complex numbers that will 120 degrees from that.  I.e.  (1/2 +- sqrt (3)/2)*cube root (2)